# PHP - extending class (basics)

Tags: php, class

Silly question, I am really new on PHP, took some codeacademy courses, but the classes part is not yet really clear to me. I am trying to work it out, and to modify the above code.

So below is a class, which checks if the user is logged on, and if so, creates an user session.

```
class Login
{
    /**
     * @var object The database connection
     */
    private $db_connection = null;
    /**
     * @var array Collection of error messages
     */
    public $errors = array();
    /**
     * @var array Collection of success / neutral messages
     */
    public $messages = array();

    /**
     * the function "__construct()" automatically starts whenever an object of this class is created,
     * you know, when you do "$login = new Login();"
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // create/read session, absolutely necessary
        session_start();

        // check the possible login actions:
        // if user tried to log out (happen when user clicks logout button)
        if (isset($_GET["logout"])) {
            $this->doLogout();
        }
        // login via post data (if user just submitted a login form)
        elseif (isset($_POST["login"])) {
            $this->dologinWithPostData();
        }
    }

    /**
     * log in with post data
     */
    private function dologinWithPostData()
    {
        // check login form contents
        if (empty($_POST['user_name'])) {
            $this->errors[] = "Username field was empty.";
        } elseif (empty($_POST['user_password'])) {
            $this->errors[] = "Password field was empty.";
        } elseif (!empty($_POST['user_name']) && !empty($_POST['user_password'])) {

            // create a database connection, using the constants from config/db.php (which we loaded in index.php)
            $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

            // change character set to utf8 and check it
            if (!$this->db_connection->set_charset("utf8")) {
                $this->errors[] = $this->db_connection->error;
            }

            // if no connection errors (= working database connection)
            if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {

                // escape the POST stuff
                $user_name = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);

                // database query, getting all the info of the selected user (allows login via email address in the
                // username field)
                $sql = "SELECT user_name, user_email, user_password_hash
                        FROM sales_users
                        WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name . "' OR user_email = '" . $user_name . "';";
                $result_of_login_check = $this->db_connection->query($sql);

                // if this user exists
                if ($result_of_login_check->num_rows == 1) {

                    // get result row (as an object)
                    $result_row = $result_of_login_check->fetch_object();

                    // using PHP 5.5's password_verify() function to check if the provided password fits
                    // the hash of that user's password
                    if (password_verify($_POST['user_password'], $result_row->user_password_hash)) {

                        // write user data into PHP SESSION (a file on your server)
                        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
                        $_SESSION['user_email'] = $result_row->user_email;
                        $_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;

                    } else {
                        $this->errors[] = "Wrong password. Try again.";
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->errors[] = "This user does not exist.";
                }
            } else {
                $this->errors[] = "Database connection problem.";
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * perform the logout
     */
    public function doLogout()
    {
        // delete the session of the user
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_destroy();
        // return a little feeedback message
        $this->messages[] = "You have been logged out.";

    }

    /**
     * simply return the current state of the user's login
     * @return boolean user's login status
     */
    public function isUserLoggedIn()
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_login_status']) AND $_SESSION['user_login_status'] == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        // default return
        return false;
    }

}
```

What I want to do, is to extend this class, and use it to get some other data from the database. So I wrote:

```
class Price extends Login
{
    public function getPrice()
    {

        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM sales_pricelist";
        $result = $Login->db_connection->query($sql);
        $result = $result->fetch_object();

        echo $result->product_name;

    }

}
```

I understand that this part is not correct at all. But it iliustrates what I want to achieve. So the question is, how should the correct version look? I was hoping that I could learn it better when seeing the exact example.

**Edit #1:**

Is this part   `$result = $Login->db_connection->query($sql);` correct? This basically means, that I am targeting db_connection from the Login class right?

**Edit #2:**

Thank you for all the comments.

So now, my `Price` class looks like this:

```
class Price extends Login
{

    public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getPrice()
    {

        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM sales_pricelist";
        $result = $this->db_connection->query($sql);
        $result = $result->fetch_object();

        echo $result->product_name;

    }

}
```

And I am trying to call use the `getPrice` like this:

```
$price = new Price();
$price->getPrice();
```

But something is missing. Any mistakes here?

Comment: Quick question: Why would you need to extend the login class? to check `isUserLoggedIn()` ?

Comment: I want to extend it just to have the db connection, and be able to execute sql written in that new class. Or am I getting this whole idea how it should work wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reference the current object with `$this` . As the child class inherits the parents methods and properties, you would access the db property as so:

```
$result = $this->db_connection->query($sql);
```

Edit as per comments

1. As noted, `$db_connection` has private scope, so unaccessable to child classes. If you wish to access it in child classes, you either need to change it to `protected` or `public`, or write a getter method in the parent, with protected or public scope:

   `protected function getDb()
    {
        return $this->db_connection;
    }`
2. re `parent::__construct()`
   The parent constructor will automatically be called unless you override the method in the child class (by writing a `__construct()` method in it. If you do that, you will need to call the parent consructor as noted;
3. Initializing the database connection
   As noted, the db connection is initialized in the `dologinWithPostData()` method. For it to be usefull for other methods, it would make more sense to initialize it in the parent constuctor.
4. General notes
   This violates all sorts of good OOP principles, such as encapsulation. Learning a decent modern MVC framework would probably give you a better grounding than following random internet tutorials

Comment: This gets my vote as that's how it is supposed to be accessed. Might want to include the `__construct() { parent::__construct(); }` of the parent and also state that extended classes can't access `private` variables, only `public` & `protected`. Especially because `$db_connection` is private so he wouldn't be able to access it in his `Price` class. Also an issue as he only instantiates the `$db_connection` variable when running `dologinWithPostData()`..

Comment: Thanks! I finally got it. I made the '$db_connection' public and it works. regarding your comment, what if I instantiate the '$db_connection' when running the 'Login''s constructor?

Comment: @Steve Perfectly written, I'd +1 again if I could haha!

Comment: Beautiful answer. Thank you very much. I will try all the mentioned ways, and research them more :) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This looks right to me at first glance. What you need is to call the parent constructor. In you Price class so that you can run your login code.

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Comment: You can indeed call the constructor in this way, but if it is the only thing you're doing in the child, you can omit the method entirely, since it is inherited.